# What does ordering.by means in this spark code fragment?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Code example:(on iPad, sorry for the pic not text)

[image]

What does `[(int,double),double]` stands for in this example?
I can not find document about it…

And why there is a `case` keyword in function?
Like Javascript, in an arrow function, `case` keyword is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the type of `sims` is `(Int, Double)` (a tuple).

`Ordering.by` signature is

```
def by[T, S](f: T => S)(implicit ord: Ordering[S]): Ordering[T] = new Ordering[T] {
```

`T` is `(Int, Double)` which is `id`

`S` is `Double` which is `similarity`

So, your function does the ordering according to the value of `similarity`.

The `case` here is used to extract the different values of the tuples. Otherwise, your function would be

```
Ordering.by[(Int, Double, Double)]( v => v._2) // 2nd element of the tuple == similarity
```